# How would you design a simple chat application using microservices?

Tags: microservices

So let's say these are my tables:

```
users
id(pk) | username

channels
id(pk) | title

members
user_id(pk, fk) | channel_id(pk, fk)

messages
id(pk) | channel_id(fk) | sender_id(fk) | text | created_at
```

From what I read about microservices, they should be able to be deployed by themselves, and have their own database.

I think that means I would have these microservices each running their own SQL instance:

Users Microservice

```
users
id(pk) | username
```

Messaging Microservice

```
channels
id(pk) | title

members
user_id(pk, fk) | channel_id(pk, fk)

messages
id(pk) | channel_id(fk) | sender_id(fk) | text | created_at
```

I read that to expose these microservices, I should have some sort of REST/GraphQL API for each one, so Messaging Microservice would have things like `getChannel()`, `createMessage()`, etc.

So my question is what should I do when I need to access data in another microservice, basically how should they talk to each other? For example, say on my frontend I enter a chat channel and want to display its messages. If I do a `getChannelMessages()`, this would return me a list of

```
{
  id: 1,
  channel_id: 32,
  sender_id: 48,
  text: 'hello world',
  created_at: some unix time
}
```

At this point, I don't know who `sender_id: 48` is, which I need to display. From there, am I supposed to call Users Microservice's API with `getUser(sender_id)` for every single message or something?

What if a user gets deleted? Feels like I have to do some extra work to reach into the other microservice to delete all of their messages and remove them from channels. Don't things get out of sync?

Lastly, doesn't this seem like a bit overkill if I only have a single frontend? Am I supposed to have a single frontend that talks to each microservice or are my microservices supposed to have their own frontends too? Maybe if this were a web app I could split URLs for each frontend or something, but multiple frontends doesn't make sense to me in the context of say, a mobile app.

Having trouble putting this all together and would appreciate any advice and clarification.

Comment: Congratulations, you have realized that patterns and paradigms are a two-edged sword. Yes it would be overkill. It makes sense separating things that could be a thing on their own. So you won't keep userdata such as their address or a phonenumber in the chat-database/service. But you would store at least the username and maybe an email address there, so you don't have to look them up every message - but only when you need to retrieve more specific data.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T So you clarify, you're saying for my above example, you'd probably just have 1 service (with 1 database + 1 API) for both users and chat? That's how I've always done it. Could an example of "more specific data" be payments? Let's say this app could take a user's credit card to store their subscriptions or something. I'd have 2 microservices: (users+chat microservice) + (payments microservice)?

Comment: yes and no. Adding the payments example you'd probably have 3 services / distinct applications: Messaging-Service, User-Service, Payment-Service. In order to cut down on the (data-)transactions between these services, each service might store a subset of the information managed by another service, e.g. the Messaging-Service will also store the username belonging to the userId, so it doesn't have to request it multiple times a second. And so forth. It's a trade-off between complexity and data-integrity